# Disable user input until thread.sleep is finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, console

So i am a beginner programmer. 
I am in my second year of learning how to program.

So I am wondering if there is a easy way to wait for the Thread.Sleep to finish in c# console application. Because when i have a thread.sleep and a console.readkey behind that.
The console.ReadKey will execute.

Could someone please explain to me how to do this.
And why this is happening if you feel like it.

Comment: Why _what_ is happening? The exact question is unclear.

Comment: What is it you want to accomplish?

Comment: Can you please provide some code to back up your chain of thoughts? Usually, if you need to pass notifications on events between the threads you would use wait handles.

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear. bassicly when you use thread sleep. it still allows for user input. il edit it.

Comment: This is a feature of threads: allow something while other things are going. In parallel. If you don't want to run in parallel, then ... do not use thread. =D

Comment: Are you saying that calling `Thread.Sleep(10000); Console.ReadKey();`, the sleep is ignored?

Comment: yes when using a library

Comment: No, when a Sleep() and a ReadKey() are on the same thread they should occur in that sequence. So your guess about the source of your problems is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so this only happens when i used some other method.

if i were to do this

```
Thread.Sleep(); //sleep 100 seconds
        Console.Read();
```

nothing happend when i pressed a button.

however using a diffrent method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntervalMessage("this is a test");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
        public static void IntervalMessage(string message)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < message.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == message.Length - 1)
            {
                Console.Write(message[i]);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(120);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(message[i]);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(110);
            }
        }
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
```

it will be able to have take input while sleeping.
Thanks for trying to help. figured it out myself.

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(120); is wainting for 120 **ms**, did you notice that?